# oAuth Instagram login

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I am trying to get access token from Instagram using oAuth 2, to use it in scopes. I couldn't understand how should I configure "redirect_uri" (tried  a lot of combinations) if I use it in native app, it means I don't need any websites to have redirected, I need redirect to app itself, after logged in. *(Maybe I explained something not correctly, because don't understand how redirect_uri works in native apps)*

In **AppDelegate.swift** added:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
        OAuthSwift.handleOpenURL(url)
    }
    return true
}
```

In **ViewController.swift**:

```
import UIKit
import OAuthSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey:    "cc6dd7ca50c74f4f92a1a8328c9d4426",
            consumerSecret: "74f6bf3c839b4e15a747a332d#######",
            authorizeUrl:   "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
            responseType:   "token"
        )
        oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(
            NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram")!,
            scope: "likes+comments", state:"INSTAGRAM",
            success: { credential, response, parameters in
                print(credential.oauth_token)
            },
            failure: { error in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        )

    }
}
```

(can't add image without url because of reputation) :

[Url schemes in project info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBeON.png)

[Instagram settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCRIO.png)

Question:

- What I am doing wrong?
- How to fix it so app can "print(credential.oauth_token)" happen.

**Fixed:**

```
NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram")!,
```

should be changed to

```
NSURL(string: "AppName://oauth-callback")!,
```

And also in Instagram settings

Comment: What did you fill in : `Valid redirect URIs:` in Instagram developer account.

Comment: As you can see on screenshot: "ig" + client id + "://authorize""

Comment: But I am getting error:  `Enter a valid website. Submission error: please fill out all required fields.` When I fill it inside App->Security->Valid redirect URIs

Comment: If it is in App->Security, try AppName://oauth-callback

Comment: See its showing error: http://imgur.com/a/JcrIv

Comment: I have same thing but it doesn't show me error. I think problem in "-"symbol in your appname. Try to change it and not use "-"

Comment: I tried removing it still the same error, can you, kindly, re-check your instagram developer app once to confirm?

Comment: my url is already added, but when i want to re-save it, it gives me same error. Seems that they changed rules of that thing. Haven't researched yet, cause it is working for me. Sorry

Comment: oh....something fishy :/

Comment: Can you look into the matter at your end?