# Android + Instagram "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"

Tags: android, redirect, uri, instagram

I read some branches  about this error, but I  can't find the answer.

I have:

```
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "fffff";
public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxx";
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "igfffff";
private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
private static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";
```

In my instagram,  I added:

Valid redirect URIs: - https://igfffff

Website URL: - http://myownsite.com

Then I  tried to use redirect URI with and without ://authorize but I catch the  error:

> {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try to replace :-**

```
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "https://igfffff";
```

Comment: Yes, it's works. Thank you. May be do you know how to add subscribers and subscribe automatically?

Comment: Can you help with the code? Or may  be you have any open example?

Comment: you want to get follower and following users list from instagram?

Comment: I need to add subscribers automatically use a  hashtag and  then delete  subscribers automatically. May be speak by skype or  email?

Comment: Kindly check its thread of comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942140/oauth-instagram-login?noredirect=1#comment68983627_36942140
 __I am stuck with redirect URIs.

Comment: you tried to delete and create once again project in instagram developer?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ: I did, but the thing is I am unable to set the URI, if I put www.google.com over there, the app redirects to google without coming back to the app.